# Variance of sampling distribution of regression coefficients depends on the specific sample values?

Tags: variance, sampling, standard-deviation, regression-coefficients

this is my first post!

I know the sampling distribution of the sample mean is $N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$.

I also know that the sampling distribution of $\hat \beta_1$ is $N(\beta_1, \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum(x-\bar x)^2})$

However, this last variance depends on the specific values for a given sample! How can that be? I have run a simulation in R just to check.

Here's a demonstration. I am creating 1000 data points with $\beta_1=2$ and $\sigma^2=1$. I then take 1000 samples of size 50, estimate $\hat \beta_1$, and then take the standard deviation of the $\hat \beta_1$s. When I do, I find that it is

```
x<-seq(-5,4.99,.01)
y<-1+2*x+rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=1)
dat<-data.frame(x,y)

betas<-vector()
sigma2<-vector()

for(i in 1:1000){
sum1<-summary(lm(data=dat[sample(nrow(dat),size = 50,replace = F),],y~x))
sum1
betas<-rbind(betas,coef(sum1)[1:2,1])
sigma2<-rbind(sigma2,sum1$sigma^2)
}

mean(betas[,2])
#1.999
sd(betas[,2])
#.0505
```

When I take a specific sample of 50 and compute the standard deviation myself, I get near the correct value

```
dat1<-dat[sample(nrow(dat),size = 50,replace = F),]
with(dat1,1/sqrt(sum((x-mean(x))^2)))
# 0.05027655
```

I'm just confused about how the population variance of the sampling distribution can be based on the actual values of $x$ in a given sample.

Comment: In regression, $x$ is treated as known, not random. More precisely, inference is conditional on the design matrix, $X$

Comment: I just wanted to comment that the two claims you make require that in 1) the samples are independent and identically distributed and normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and in 2) the error terms are independent and normally distributed with mean 0 and constant variance.

Answer (score 2):

In the case where your predictors are nonrandom, this should be intuitive because

1. the more data you have, the smaller the variance, and
2. the more dispersed the $x$ data are, the smaller the variance.

I suspect you are worried about the duality of sample and population. You're probably saying to yourself, data cannot be a parameter because it is random. And that's still appropriate to stick with that intuition here. The assumptions you are using, however, say that $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are **nonrandom**. They are not a random sample.

Comment: The x values are selected by design. Taylor's comments 1 and 2 are very true.  Note that if all the xs are close together the slope is not very accurate. If you take 1 point far away from a set of closely together xs could lead t a big change in th estimate of slope.

Comment: Thanks Taylor and @Glen_b. I think I understand. So there is no true "population" value for for the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of a regression coefficient (that is sample independent)? Like, there is no analytic expression for the true value? I guess that just seems counter-intuitive because the sampling distribution of the mean is so easy, sigma^2/sqrt(n). But if I repeatedly estimate new regression coefficients based on samples from the population, can I think of the standard deviation of this empirical sampling distribution as the "true" sd of the sampling distribution?

Comment: @nrw "So there is no true "population" value for for the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of a regression coefficient (that is sample independent)?" <- It's $\sigma/\sqrt{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2}$. "But if I repeatedly estimate new regression coefficients based on samples from the population, can I think of the standard deviation of this empirical sampling distribution as the "true" sd of the sampling distribution?" <- You'll have to be more precise. Perhaps consider asking another question on the site.